# angular-cli webpack.cofig.js does not work

Tags: angular, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I have an angular application which has a devDependency -> `"@angular/cli": "^1.0.3"`, in order to reduce the size of the `vendor.bundle.js` (~4.5MB), I am in the process of configuring the `webpack.config.js` file. I have ejected webpack.config.js using `ng eject` and I made multiple changes for minification, uglification, compression (gzip), Dedupe,  etc,. But I dont see any of these configuration changse are getting affected and the size of the vendor.bundle.js isn't reducing anyway.
Below is the copy of webpack.config.js (which is pretty huge as extracted out of @angular/cli, apologies for that), Can someone point me the reason what I am missing in it and how I can successfully reduce the size of the app?

```
const path = require('path');
const ProgressPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProgressPlugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const postcssUrl = require('postcss-url');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const { NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin } = require('webpack');
const { GlobCopyWebpackPlugin, BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('@angular/cli/plugins/webpack');
const { CommonsChunkPlugin } = require('webpack').optimize;
const { AotPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const nodeModules = path.join(process.cwd(), 'node_modules');
const entryPoints = ["inline","polyfills","sw-register","scripts","styles","vendor","main"];
const minimizeCss = false;
const baseHref = "";
const deployUrl = "";
const postcssPlugins = function () {
        // safe settings based on: https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano/issues/358#issuecomment-283696193
        const importantCommentRe = /@preserve|@license|[@#]\s*source(?:Mapping)?URL|^!/i;
        const minimizeOptions = {
            autoprefixer: false,
            safe: true,
            mergeLonghand: false,
            discardComments: { remove: (comment) => !importantCommentRe.test(comment) }
        };
        return [
            postcssUrl({
                url: (URL) => {
                    // Only convert root relative URLs, which CSS-Loader won't process into require().
                    if (!URL.startsWith('/') || URL.startsWith('//')) {
                        return URL;
                    }
                    if (deployUrl.match(/:\/\//)) {
                        // If deployUrl contains a scheme, ignore baseHref use deployUrl as is.
                        return ${deployUrl.replace(/\/$/, '')}${URL};
                    }
                    else if (baseHref.match(/:\/\//)) {
                        // If baseHref contains a scheme, include it as is.
                        return baseHref.replace(/\/$/, '') +
                            /${deployUrl}/${URL}.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Join together base-href, deploy-url and the original URL.
                        // Also dedupe multiple slashes into single ones.
                        return /${baseHref}/${deployUrl}/${URL}.replace(/\/\/+/g, '/');
                    }
                }
            }),
            autoprefixer(),
        ].concat(minimizeCss ? [cssnano(minimizeOptions)] : []);
    };




module.exports = {
"devtool": "source-map",
"resolve": {
    "extensions": [
    ".ts",
    ".js"
    ],
    "modules": [
    "./node_modules"
    ]
},
"resolveLoader": {
    "modules": [
    "./node_modules"
    ]
},
"entry": {
    "main": [
    "./src\\main.ts"
    ],
    "scripts": [
    "script-loader!./node_modules\\jquery\\dist\\jquery.js",
    "script-loader!./node_modules\\tether\\dist\\js\\tether.js",
    "script-loader!./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\js\\bootstrap.js"
    ],
    "styles": [
    "./node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css",
    "./node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css",
    "./node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css",
    "./node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css",
    "./src\\styles.css"
    ]
},
"output": {
    "path": path.join(process.cwd(), "dist"),
    "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
    "chunkFilename": "[id].chunk.js"
},
"module": {
    "rules": [
    {
        "enforce": "pre",
        "test": /\.js$/,
        "loader": "source-map-loader",
        "exclude": [
        /\/node_modules\//
        ]
    },
    {
        "test": /\.json$/,
        "loader": "json-loader"
    },
    {
        "test": /\.html$/,
        "loader": "raw-loader"
    },
    {
        "test": /\.(eot|svg)$/,
        "loader": "file-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]"
    },
    {
        "test": /\.(jpg|png|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|cur|ani)$/,
        "loader": "url-loader?name=[name].[hash:20].[ext]&limit=10000"
    },
    {
        "exclude": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "exclude": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "precision": 8,
            "includePaths": []
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "exclude": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "exclude": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
        "exports-loader?module.exports.toString()",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "paths": []
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.css$/,
        "use": [
        "style-loader",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
        "use": [
        "style-loader",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "sass-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "precision": 8,
            "includePaths": []
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.less$/,
        "use": [
        "style-loader",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "less-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\bootstrap\\dist\\css\\bootstrap.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\themes\\omega\\theme.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\primeng\\resources\\primeng.min.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "node_modules\\font-awesome\\css\\font-awesome.css"),
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
        ],
        "test": /\.styl$/,
        "use": [
        "style-loader",
        {
            "loader": "css-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "importLoaders": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "postcss-loader",
            "options": {
            "ident": "postcss",
            "plugins": postcssPlugins
            }
        },
        {
            "loader": "stylus-loader",
            "options": {
            "sourceMap": false,
            "paths": []
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        "test": /\.ts$/,
        "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"    // AOT compilation
    }
    ]
},
"plugins": [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(), //dedupe similar code 
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(), //minify everything
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),//Merge chunks 
    new CompressionPlugin({
    asset: "[path].gz[query]",
    algorithm: "gzip",
    test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
    threshold: 10240,
    minRatio: 0
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(
    {analyzerMode: 'server',
    analyzerHost: '127.0.0.1',
    analyzerPort: 8888,
    reportFilename: 'report.html',
    defaultSizes: 'parsed',
    openAnalyzer: true,
    generateStatsFile: true,
    statsFilename: 'stats.json',
    statsOptions: null,
    logLevel: 'info'}),
    new NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new GlobCopyWebpackPlugin({
    "patterns": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
    ],
    "globOptions": {
        "cwd": "D:\\Users\\duraimurugan.r\\Desktop\\latest_source_5.12\\apollo-accounting-ui\\src",
        "dot": true,
        "ignore": "**/.gitkeep"
    }
    }),
    new ProgressPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    "template": "./src\\index.html",
    "filename": "./index.html",
    "hash": false,
    "inject": true,
    "compile": true,
    "favicon": false,
    "minify": {
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeComments: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
    },
    "cache": true,
    "showErrors": true,
    "chunks": "all",
    "excludeChunks": [],
    "title": "Webpack App",
    "xhtml": true,
    "chunksSortMode": function sort(left, right) {
        let leftIndex = entryPoints.indexOf(left.names[0]);
        let rightindex = entryPoints.indexOf(right.names[0]);
        if (leftIndex > rightindex) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (leftIndex < rightindex) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }),
    new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({}),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    "name": "inline",
    "minChunks": null
    }),
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
    "name": "vendor",
    "minChunks": (module) => module.resource && module.resource.startsWith(nodeModules),
    "chunks": [
        "main"
    ]
    }),
    new AotPlugin({
    "mainPath": "main.ts",
    "hostReplacementPaths": {
        "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
    },
    "exclude": [],
    "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.json",
    "skipCodeGeneration": true
    })
],
"node": {
    "fs": "empty",
    "global": true,
    "crypto": "empty",
    "tls": "empty",
    "net": "empty",
    "process": true,
    "module": false,
    "clearImmediate": false,
    "setImmediate": false
},
"devServer": {
    "historyApiFallback": true
}
};
```

Comment: How are you running webpack with this config?

Comment: I did not use the right command to run the app. That cost me an hour. This is working now.